How to configure ftp in Jboss EAP 7.4
Our application is using ftp protocol to send/receive files. Currently it's deployed in WebLogic and we are planning to migrate it to JBoss.
I am wondering how to configure ftp in Jboss. Do I need to add any resource adapter?
Can someone please help on this.

How is the FTP configured? Is it something like:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50339_01/doc.12/e36380/T557833T561744.htm#T581571

I just wonder is you can not setup similar to:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_soa_platform/5/html/esb_programmers_guide/configuring_an_ftp_provider

@MirceaVutcovici - yes, in weblogic it was configured same as https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50339_01/doc.12/e36380/T557833T561744.htm#T581571 and planning to configure similar on Jboss EAP. Is it possible?
